# MySQL Error Code 1005, Despite same data types

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create three linked tables in MySQL but the script I have written gives me `Error code: 1005. Can't create table 'xxx.MagPage' (errno: 150)`. Checking other threads with this error code has shown me that this error can occur when two linked columns have different data types, however all foreign keys have the same type as the linked column.

These are just example tables, but use the same setup and datatypes as my real tables. Basically, it is a database of magazines. Each magazine had a unique ID, and has issues. These issues are uniquely identifiable by their magazine ID and their issue number put together (multiple magazines can have the same issue number). Each page of a magazine has a number and is uniquely identified by the combination of its magazine id, issue number and page number. (Multiple magazines can have a page number 4, multiple issues can have a page number 4).

```
CREATE TABLE Magazine(
    id CHAR(14) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE MagIssue(
    mag_id CHAR(14) NOT NULL,
    issue_num INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(mag_id, issue_num),
    FOREIGN KEY(mag_id) REFERENCES Magazine(id),
    CONSTRAINT U_Issue UNIQUE (mag_id, issue_num)
);

CREATE TABLE MagPage(
    mag_id CHAR(14) NOT NULL,
    issue_num INTEGER NOT NULL,
    page_num INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(mag_id, issue_num, page_num),
    FOREIGN KEY(mag_id) REFERENCES Magazine(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(issue_num) REFERENCES MagIssue(issue_num),
    CONSTRAINT U_Page UNIQUE (mag_id, issue_num, page_num)
);
```

Comment: Mostly a guess here, but it could be `FOREIGN KEY(issue_num) REFERENCES MagIssue(issue_num)`.  The key on the target table is both columns, not just one of them.  The FK referencing it would likely need to be both columns as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary key on `MagIssue` has two parts.  You need to reference both:

```
FOREIGN KEY (mag_id, issue_num) REFERENCES MagIssue(mag_id issue_num),
```

I am not a fan of composite primary keys.  You are also repeating references across multiple tables.  And integers tend to be better for indexes than strings (a marginal optimization).

I would instead suggest:

```
CREATE TABLE Magazines (
    mag_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    mag_key CHAR(14) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE MagIssues (
    magissues_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    mag_id INT NOT NULL,
    issue_num INT NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (mag_id, issue_num),
    FOREIGN KEY(mag_id) REFERENCES Magazine (mag_id)
);

CREATE TABLE MagPages (
    magpages_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    magissues_id INT NULL NULL,
    issue_num INTEGER NOT NULL,
    page_num INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(magissues_id) REFERENCES MagIssues (magissues_id),
    CONSTRAINT U_Page UNIQUE (magissues_id, issue_num, page_num)
);
```